# Is it possible to share application object across Web Role instance?

Tags: c#, azure

I am going to migrate a existing application (single machine) to Windows Azure. And it is stored somethings on HttpApplicationState.

Is it able to share application object across Web Role instance? Thanks.

Comment: HttpApplicationState is not shared across web farm or web garden (multiple worker processes on the same machine). Could you describe in more details what kind of data you need to share and how it is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  If you want state shared between instances in a web role then each instance will need to reference some common data storage (e.g. an SQL Azure table) each time you want it.  Of course you must also be careful of concurrency issues.

Comment: AppFabric caching would be good service to use for this (when it's out if CTP next month)

Answer (score 1):

As Knightpfhor stated, AppFabric Cache is a very good (and easy-to-use) service for sharing across multiple instances. It will be officially live by end-of-April, as announced at MIX a few days ago.

You'll just need to manage object lifetime and approprate cache size.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to David M - you can create an ASP.NET session state provider for the Azure AppFabric Caching service. There is a sample in the Windows azure training kit:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=413e88f8-5966-4a83-b309-53b7b77edf78&displaylang=en

Here's a walk through:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg457897